# A word to describe punishing a person(s) or group for having different beliefs?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am currently writing a paper which is based on different perspectives involving the current "War on Drugs" policy and compare them to similar policies of the past where individuals were imprisoned, punished, or killed for having a different belief. The point I am trying to make in one section is that current policies protect individuals who support the prohibition while those who oppose prohibition are often punished unjustly.

I cannot seem to find a word that describes punishing/imprisoning a group of people for having a different belief.

I guess it would be 'discrimination' but far more severe.

Comment: Hi Michael, welcome to English Language & Usage. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. You must include **a sample sentence** demonstrating how the word would be used." [My emphasis]. You can add these details by clicking on the [edit] link. :-)

Answer (score 4):

> [**Persecution**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/persecute) - to treat (someone) cruelly or unfairly especially because of race or religious or political beliefs.
>
> [**Oppress**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oppress) - to treat (a person or group of people) in a cruel or unfair way
>
> [**Tyrannize**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/tyrannize) - Rule or treat (someone) despotically or cruelly

```
Source: Merriam-Webster; Oxford Dictionary
```